# Finding similarities between two Facebook users using FQL

Tags: sql, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to find the similarities between two users of my application.  I have tested the below query for just the interests attribute and it works fine:

```
SELECT interests FROM user WHERE uid=me() AND interests IN 
(SELECT interests FROM user WHERE uid = $targ_id)
```

I want to extend this to finding the similarities over the following attributes: `movies, tv, music, books`.  Modifying the `SELECT` statements is trivial but I am unsure how to do the `IN` clause.  This is what I tried doing:

```
    SELECT interests, movies, tv, music, books FROM user WHERE uid=me() 
AND (interests, movies, tv, music, books) IN 
    (SELECT interests, music, tv, movies, books FROM user WHERE uid = $targ_id)
```

This comes up with the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#601) Parser error: unexpected ',' at position 82.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 601
  }
}
```

How can I adjust this FQL query to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to compare two users interests using the FQL `IN` operator. The fields `interests`, `movies`, `books`, etc. are strings, not an array. You need to use a string operation like `strpos()` or `substr()`. FQL doesn't have a `LIKE` operation.

You could try to write a huge FQL query where you split each result on the commas, and compare these to one another, but I think it's going to be a lot easier to bring these in to your script and do this on the back end. Otherwise you'd end up with a situation where my `movies` are "Jaws, Tron" and your movies are "Jaws, Star Wars, Tron" and you won't have a match because the strings are different.

Comment: Ah thanks cpilko - you're right!  They are stored in strings - damn.  I'm a bit confused by what you meant in your last paragraph - are you saying that you recommend the big query method?

Comment: No, I don't recommend it. I don't think I'd event attempt to write it for one field because I wouldn't be able to keep the strpos and substrs straight. Get the data and analyze it on your server.

Comment: ok, thank you!  So something along the lines of: 1)  Get profile information for both users in array form. 2)  For each parameter, explode string and compare the values.  If there is a match then add it to a "commonDetails" array.  3) Output array ?

Comment: Sure. Something like that could work. I don't know what the goals of your app are. You might want to store all of this in a data in your database at each login, so you can match users without having to make API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to configure permissions and extended permissions?

Your request has an error. You can't use multiple columns in close `AND`. Maybe you should try this:

```
SELECT interests, movies, tv, music, books FROM user 
WHERE uid=me() 
AND (interests) IN (SELECT interests FROM user WHERE uid = $targ_id) 
AND (movies) IN (SELECT movies FROM user WHERE uid = $targ_id) 
AND (tv) IN (SELECT tv FROM user WHERE uid = $targ_id) 
AND (music) IN (SELECT music FROM user WHERE uid = $targ_id)
```

Comment: Hi Damien - yeah, I am fairly certain I have configured the permissions correctly.  The error seems to indicate that the problem is to do with the syntax I have written.  I think the problem is to do with the way I have done the IN statement.  I can't think of a way to do this without specifying the subquery for each separate parameter... which is INSANITY!

Comment: Ok, I saw the problem, your FQL request contains errors. I've tried this : 
`SELECT interests, movies, tv, music, books FROM user WHERE uid=me() 
AND (interests) IN 
    (SELECT interests FROM user WHERE uid =  $targ_id)
AND (movies) IN 
    (SELECT movies FROM user WHERE uid =  $targ_id)
AND (tv) IN 
    (SELECT tv FROM user WHERE uid =  $targ_id)
AND (music) IN 
    (SELECT music FROM user WHERE uid =  $targ_id)`

And it seems to work.
Maybe you can shrink it ;)

Comment: haha yeah I was trying to avoid this - although this is better than what I proposed before!  I tried your query and an error doesn't get thrown but it's not returning the correct data for some reason.  If I get rid of everything after the (interests) IN (SELECT interests FROM user WHERE uid = $targ_id) clause it returns data but if I add in the rest it doesn't.  It looks like the query could be telling it to return the data only in cases where all of the conditions are true for some weird reason...

Comment: Have you tried your querys on the function `FQL Query` in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) ?

Comment: Yeah, that's where I'm testing it.  I just found this http://explainextended.com/2009/06/17/efficient-exists/ - this type of structure is allowed MySQL syntax "(val1, val2) IN (SELECT val1, val1 FROM t_inner)", but MySQL actually interprets it in terms of a join, which I heard it forbidden in FQL.  So maybe I can't do it this way?

Comment: Thanks for the help Damien!  Unfortunately the way I was trying wouldn't work because the values for each attribute are stored in strings, so if they don't match exactly it screws up!  Appreciate the help though man